# Get id of row selected using angular.js using ngSelect or ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

I'm creating a dynamic table using angular.js and it gets populated with results from a study. I need to be able to show more data about each of these studies if a user clicks on that specific row in the table. Here's what the table looks like.. I'm thinking I have to use ngOptions or ngSelect, but I'm not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td class="center" id="table-header">Date</td>
              <td class="center" id="table-header">Study</td>
              <td class="center" id="table-header">Sample</td>
              <td class="center" id="table-header">File</td>
              <td class="center" id="table-header">Big Data</td>
              <td class="center" id="table-header">Action</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody ng-repeat="study in studies | filter: filter_name">
            <tr>
              <td class="center">{{ study.created_at }}</td>
              <td class="center">{{ study.study }}</td>
              <td class="center">{{ study.sample }}</td>
              <td class="center">{{ study.fastq }}</td>
              <td class="center">{{ study.bigData }}</td>
              <td class="center">
               <div class="dropdown center">
                  <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Action
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <li id="list-item">Continue</li>
                    <li id="list-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#more-metadata-modal">More Data</li>
                    <li id="list-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-metadata-modal">Edit</li>
                    <li id="list-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-metadata-modal">Delete</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: couple of notices first, `ng-repeat` should be in the `<tr>` because that's what you want to repeat (rows) right? also you have many elements with the same `id` attribute, id must be unique.  So how do you fetch the _more data_, through an ajax call for example or they are already known?

Answer (score 0):

use ng-Click and pass the object or the id from which you can fetch more values for the selected item.

```
ng-click=showMore(study);
```

and using this styudy you can populate a scope object that can be used in a modal panel for that particular study object

Comment: added a 'ng-click = showMore(study)' and in the angular controller i have this code..  $scope.showMore = function(data) {
  console.log("current data",data);
  $scope.study = data;
 };

Comment: it console.logs the correct data on clicks, but doesnt bind the new variable to scope? cannot figure this one out

Comment: That is a bit weird because if u are getting the value in the log that should assign. Try $cope.study=angular.copy(data)

Comment: Ok, I really don't understand this.. I tried the angular.copy and it didn't work but I can also console.log the $scope.study but only in the angular controller.

Comment: Scope.study will be accessible only in the controller. Where do u want it??

Comment: I need to populate a modal with this data on the front-end, basically a user clicks the dropdown menu, a modal pops up with more data about that study.

Comment: If you want to use a new controller for the modal simply use service or factory to pass the data to another controller from the current one